# Rename categories in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, categorical-data, sklearn-pandas

I have categories like:

```
Bathing 
Cooking 
Cleaning 
Cooking and Drinking 
Cooking, cleaning and drinking 
Domestic use
```

I want to rename them to about 3 categories, say

```
 Cooking 
 Drinking 
 Cleaning
```

```py
df3=pd.Categorical(['cooking', 'domestic use', 'cleaning', 'drinking'])
```

So that I get something like this

```
df3.rename_categories({'cooking', 'drinking', 'other'})
```

Comment: you find her [Dataframe.rename() documentation ](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html?highlight=dataframe%20rename#pandas.DataFrame.rename)

Answer (score 0):

What I just understand and assume is you want to categories any related ones,

```
# Create a mapping of old category names to new category names
mapping = {
    'Bathing': 'Cleaning',
    'Cooking': 'Cooking',
    'Cleaning': 'Cleaning',
    'Cooking and Drinking': 'Other',
    'Cooking, cleaning and drinking': 'Other',
    'Domestic use': 'Other',
}

# Use the `rename` method to rename the categories
df3 = df3.rename(columns=mapping)
```